# C++ Visual Studio Debugger Error with Enumeration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I'm building a bulls and cows game(have to guess a word through command prompt) I'm having a problem in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 where I'm using an enum to check for input errors.If there is an error, there is supposed to be an error in the debugger like Word_Length or if its ok it should display OK.
Then when I run the debugger, instead of displaying a message like OK or Word_Length it displays some numbers.

Could I be doing something wrong? Or is it VS.. I find it weird because I'm doing this alongside a c++ course so the code should be fine.
Thanks for any help!

--Code--------

Here is where I declare the Enumeration

```
enum class EGuessStatus
{
    OK,
    Not_Isogram,
    Wrong_Length,
    Not_Lowercase
};
```

Here I say if the word length is not right, return the error

```
else if (Guess.length() != GetHiddenWordLength())   //if the word length is 
                                                    //wrong, return an error
    {
        return EGuessStatus::Wrong_Length;

    }
```

And then I say if the Guess is OK, return OK

```
else {      //otherwise, return ok
        return EGuessStatus::OK;
    }
```

And here it is in the main.cpp where I then mark it to debug.

```
EGuessStatus Status = BCGame.checkGuessValidity(Guess);
```

In this situation the word is 'planet' and as you can see, the debugger spews out weird numbers.

[This is an image of the debugger once I input 'planet' which is supposed to be correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbqtl.png)

Comment: A the exact moment your have screenshoted, Status has not yet been initialized, because debuggers usually highlight the *next* statement that is to be executed. Press next statement and check again. If the problem persists please edit your question.

Comment: That's not a " weird number", that's `0x'CCCC'CCCC`. Typical uninitialized value in MSVC debug builds.

Comment: @MSalters so what does that mean for my code?

Comment: @iMarioOfficial: Well, as patatahooligan points out, you've taken a picture at the moment where `Status` is defined, but not yet initialized (as you've stopped the execution there). So that uninitialized variable holding `0xCCCCCCCCC` is not surprising at all.

Comment: @MSalters ohh ok i get what you're saying but now that I put the red dot thing(lol) after Status it simply doesn't run.

Comment: Doesn't run? Do you mean it crashes, or it just doesn't hit the breakpoint (red dot)? If the latter, make sure you are running a debug build and that you put your breakpoint on an actual code line and not a comment or an empty line. In any case, you can keep the breakpoint where it is and press F10 once you hit it to execute a single statement. If it crashes pinpoint the exact point using F10 and report back. EDIT: even better strip your program down to the aboslute minimum that still compiles and reproduces your probem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @patatahooligan I answered myself. I had the wrong debug setting(i was on auto should have been on locals) Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I feel Dumb.
On the debugger, I clicked Auto instead of locals.
When I checked locals the proper response displayed!
Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question but it seems like you're trying to convert an enum (who's underlying type is an integer) into a string representation?

If so then you can use a lookup table. I use std::map and map off a human readable message to each of the enums. You can then do 'std::string msg = lookup_map_.at(enum);'.